# How do I end a loop on Turtle using the following code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import turtle

flower = turtle.Turtle()
flower.color("black", "red")


def draw_flower(d, n, p):
    for num in range(n):
        flower.forward(d)
        flower.lt(180 - (180 * (n-2))/n)
    for tilt in range(p):
        flower.lt(360/p)
        draw_flower(d, n, p)


draw_flower(50, 8, 4)
turtle.done()
```

d is the length of each side, n is the number of total sides, p is the number of times I want it to repeat. The first loop will draw a polygon. I want to repeat that for p times until it shows something like a flower, and I want to break it out. 
I know there are other coding ways to make it such that it does not loop. But based on the above code, how do I break out of it when it draws exactly the number p that I want it to draw?

Comment: Hi Jack, you are new to programming, I think? If you enter say the value of 10 for n and p, how do you describe the difference between what happens and what you want to happen?

Comment: @TimRichardson n will be number of sides for a polygon. So it will show up as a 10 sided polygon. And this 10-sided polygon will rotate with a tilt at 360/p degree left, 10 times. So it forms like a flower. But problem is, even after rotating 10 times, it continues drawing on the spot. How do I stop that?

Comment: to stop, you have to work out why it is happening. Try commenting out the second loop (you put a # in the front of the three lines). If you really can't get the flow, work through it with a pencil and piece of paper, pretending to be the computer. Or better probably, use a tool that lets you step through the code one line a a time. It seems odd that in the second loop you are calling draw_flower() again, this is why I don't think you understand the flow of your code. Hint: another famous technique is to print ("loop1") and print("loop2") statements in your code.